# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date/time format: 2016-01-21T00:57:03.126+0500

Tags: android, datetime, datetimepicker, simpledateformat, datetime-format

I am setting date and time using this method...

```
calendar.set(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
```

When fetching `DateTimeStamp`, and setting in `Event` object, I am facing an error

> NumberFormatException: Invalid date/time format:

```
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));//This Line causing it 
EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime().setDateTime(startDateTime).setTimeZone(calendar.getTimeZone().toString());
event.setStart(start);
```

Comment: Skip the String formatting, and just instantiate the `DateTime` with the `Date` from the `Calendar` instance. That is, `new DateTime(calendar.getTime())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved by using "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" this format.
As DateTime accepts RFC3339 where zone ('z') is written in quotes